# Python Regex validation

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python.

I'm trying to ensure a username contains ONLY alpha characters (only a-z). I have the below code. If I type digits only (e.g. 7777) it correctly throws the error. If I type numbers and letters mix, but I START with a number, it also rejects. But if I start with a letter (a-z) and then have numbers in the string as well, it accepts it as correct. Why?

```
def register():
    uf = open("user.txt","r")
    un = re.compile(r'[a-z]')
    up = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9()$%_/.]*$')
    print("Register new user:\n")
    new_user = input("Please enter a username:\n-->")
    if len(new_user) > 10:
        print("That username is too long. Max 10 characters please.\n")
        register()
    #elif not un.match(new_user):
    elif not re.match('[a-z]',new_user):
        print("That username is invalid. Only letters allowed, no numbers or special characters.\n")
        register()
    else:
        print(f"Thanks {new_user}")
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: re.match just looks for a match with the pattern at the beginning of the string. Your pattern however has no +/*, so it only looks for the first character. If it matches [a-z] it passes. Try "[a-z]+"

Comment: What tst said + please use a loop, not a recursive calls to `register`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [`re.match` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) say:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.

That's exactly what's happening in your case: a letter in the beginning of the string will satisfy the match. Try the expression `[a-z]+$` which will make sure that the match expands till the end of the string.

You can check the length on the same go: `[a-z]{1,10}$`.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use `isalpha()`?

```
string = '333'
print(string.isalpha()) # False

string = 'a33'
print(string.isalpha()) # False

string = 'aWWff'
print(string.isalpha()) # True
```

Answer (score 2):

in your code, `uf`, `un` and `up` are unused variables.

the only point where you *validate* something is the line `elif not re.match('[a-z]',new_user):`, and you just check if there is **at least** one lowercase char.

To ensure that a variable contains only letters, use: `elif not re.match('^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$',new_user):`

in the regex `^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$` you find:

- `^` : looks for the start of the line
- `[a-zA-Z]` : looks for chars between *a* and *z* and between *A* and *Z*
- `{1,10}` : ensure that the char specified before (letter) is repeated between 1 and 10 times. As [LhasaDad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266482/python-regex-validation/59266616#comment104741888_59266616) is suggesting in the comments, you may want to increase the minimum number of characters, e.g. to 4: `{4,10}`. We don't know what this username is for, but 1 char seems in any case too low.
- `$` : search for the end of the line

Since you were looking for a RegEx, I've produced and explained one, but [Guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266579/3032364) is more pythonic.

**IMPORTANT**:
You're not asking for this, but you may encounter an error you're not expecting: since you're calling a function inside itself, you have a [recursive function](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/). If the user provides too many times (more than 1000) the wrong username, you'll receive a `RecursionError`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I got it to work using bereal's answer, but I can see I need to relook the entire thing to make it work better. Will go through all of your comments and do some additional research.

Comment: I would strongly consider Gsk's answer.  if it had the limit on number of matches from some min number (say 4) to 10.  I think it would be the best answer.

Comment: a one character user name is really to short  for most systems....

Comment: @LhasaDad thanks for the suggestion, I've implemented it in the answer